# Using BinaryFormatter in a sequential manner in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryfiles, binary-data

Note: I'm aware about the disadvantages of using `BinaryFormatter` in large files. But this is a homework for my friend:

(.Net Framework 4)I have created a simple `Person` class which should be serialized and written in a binary file.

- For insertion, here's how it goes: Open/Create File, Seek end of the file, Add a serialized `Person` object, close the file. I don't want to serialize a `List<Person>` and write it all at once.
- For Reading (based on the `index` parameter): Open the file, seek the `index` position (based on object length), deserialize the object at `index`, return the object.
- Deletion: just like reading the record at `index` position, go to index position, delete it, save the file.

I'm not sure if using the `BinaryFormatter` is the right way to do this. e.g for insert, I've seen examples like:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open);
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(fs, person);
fs.Close();
```

which causes all the data in file to be lost and the file will only contain the `person` object. How can I do the Binary read/write/delete of objects in a sequential way in a file? My guess for insertion was to use another stream, serialize the object into that stream. write the stream to a byte array and use that byte array to write to the end of my main file stream. But I couldn't think of a suitable way for insert/delete operations. Any better suited approach to use instead of `BinaryFormatter`?

Note: To be more clear, he told me the teacher wants them to calculate the amount of time for each operation.
Thank you.

Comment: *append* is usually possible (although BF wouldn't be my first choice here); but *delete* and *insert* require you to move all the subsequent data... which is usually a problem

Comment: @MarcGravell: okay... I seem to be lost on how to fetch just one record to read at a time.

Comment: well, what happens when you try reading currently? Personally, I'd be using a documented-as-appendable format here... virtually nothing is documented about what BF will do - the implementation particulars are private. For BF you can, if necessary, write a subclassed `Stream` implementation and restrict the length. It just isn't how I'd do it! (for the record, I'd use protobuf-net, with `[Serialize|Deserialize]WithLengthPrefix`, which is a: documented in an open spec as appendable, and b: self-limiting (it won't over-read). Not sure that helps your friend, though.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks, I'm with you on `protobuf-net`. A shame I have to use `BinaryFormatter`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct except for the first line:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Append)
```

That will allow the `formatter.Serialize(fs,person)` to append itself to the file.

```
var listFromFile = new List<Person>();    

using (var fileStream = new FileStream("C:\file.dat", FileMode.Open))
{
    var bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    while (fileStream.Position != fileStream.Length)
    {
         list.Add((Person)bFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream));
    }
}
```

That should work to get the list from the file, as far as insertion goes...you may have to rewrite the objects after you read them with the new object inserted, same with deletion.

Comment: @Kamyar edited to show how you can read, and deleting should be simple after you've read them in